# 3 column divs not aligned horizontally

Tags: html

New to Stackoverflow.

I have a three column div that is not stacking horizontally. Here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcGUq.png. The link to the dev site: http://wearemoxie.com/haplusd/

I have tried several CSS hacks, but cannot get the divs to align horizontally. Thoughts?

The HTML:

```
<!--EDITORIAL-->
    <div id="editorial-container" >

        <div id="editorial">
                    <div id="content-1">
                        <p>LEFT</p>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="content-2">
                        <div id="content-2-1">
                            <p>MIDDLE</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>


                        </div>
                        <div id="content-2-2">
                            <p>RIGHT</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <!--END EDITORIAL-->
```

The CSS:

```
/*Editorial*/
#editorial-container{
    z-index:999;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    margin-top:80px;
    position:relative;
    width: 100%;
    float:left;

}

#content-1 {
    float:left;
    width:240px;
    background:#bfb;
}
#content-2 {
    float:right;
    width:720px;
}
#content-2-1 {
    float:left;
    width:480px;
    background:#ddf;
}
#content-2-2 {
    float:right;
    width:240px;
    background:#dff;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you're nesting the way that you are?

Comment: To eventually create dynamic blocks for Drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Just had to remove:

white-space: pre-wrap;

Issue solved.